# Is it possible to animate a gradient on text in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want it to be a gradient on a link that animates across on hover... other than making a gif image I don't see any scripts like this, but this seems to be closest to what I am looking for..

**css**

```css
.a:hover {
  font-size: 20px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#111));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#caca5a', endColorstr='#909501');
}
```

**js**

```javascript
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
            var iAniSpeed = 2000;
        var sBgColor = 'gold';
        $('#headerWrap').hover(function(){
          $('li a:hover').animate( { backgroundColor: sBgColor }, iAniSpeed);
            return false;       
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any ideas? if this already exists, sorry.. I couldn't find it, searched for a while...

Comment: SVG might be a better option in cross-browser terms.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome unfortunately does not support animated gradients (hey, guess what, IE *does*! Yay!)

However depending on the case you may be able to get by simply by animating the `background-position` property to slide the gradient - note that you can define colour stops beyond the end of the gradient!